# Making adjacency matrix using group information

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I am relatively new to R and I am have issues in creating an adjacency matrix using group characteristics.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
distid villageid  hhid group1 group2 group3 group4 
1        1         111  0        1     0        0
1        1         112  1        1     1        0
1        2         121  1        1     0        1 
1        2         122  1        0     0        1
2        1         211  1        1     0        0
2        1         212  1        1     1        1
2        2         221  0        0     1        0
2        2         222  0        1     1        0
```

I need to create an adjacency matrix where if a hhid is in the same distid, villageid and group then they are all fully connected.

So my final matrix should look something like this

```
hhid  111    112  121   122    211   212   221 222
111    0     1     0     0       0    0     0   0
112    1     0     0     0       0    0     0   0  
121    0     0     0     1       0    0     0   0
122    0     0     0     0       0    0     0   0 
211    0     0     0     0       0    1     0   0
212    0     0     0     0       1    0     0   0 
221    0     0     0     0       0    0     0   1
222    0     0     0     0       0    0     1   0
```

Comment: What does it mean for "group 1 to be at the district level"?  The adjacency matrix shown is not symmetric.  Please clarify and fix the question.

Comment: I have edited the question. I need to create an adjacency matrix using the fact that if hhid is in same distid and villageid having the same affiliation then its connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that what is wanted is that two elements are regarded as adjacent if they are in the same group, dist and village.

Using the input in the Note create the adjacency matrices for groups, for distid and for villageid and then multiply them together and zero out the diagonal.

```
m1 <- sign(crossprod(t(DF[-(1:3)])))
m2 <- +outer(DF$distid, DF$distid, "==")
m3 <- +outer(DF$villageid, DF$villageid, "==")
m4 <- 1 - diag(nrow(DF))
m <- m1 * m2 * m3 * m4
dimnames(m) <- list(DF$hhid, DF$hhid)
```

giving:

```
> m
    111 112 121 122 211 212 221 222
111   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
112   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
121   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
122   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
211   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
212   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
221   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
222   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

### Graph

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m)
plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

The input in reproducible form.

```
Lines <- "distid villageid  hhid group1 group2 group3 group4 
1        1         111  0        1     0        0
1        1         112  1        1     1        0
1        2         121  1        1     0        1 
1        2         122  1        0     0        1
2        1         211  1        1     0        0
2        1         212  1        1     1        1
2        2         221  0        0     1        0
2        2         222  0        1     1        0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I had a question regarding the dimensions. When you use  (t(DF[4:7])))  I get 7 is the number of variables in the data frame but why do you use 4 as the row. Is it the number of groups ?

Comment: `t(DF[4:7])` is a 4x8 matrix -- not a data frame.  If we call it `M` then `crossprod(M[, i], M[, j])` is the number of groups that the hhid's in rows i and j of `DF` have in common.  For example, for i = 2 and j = 3 it gives 2 because the hhid's in the 2nd and 3rd rows of DF have 2 groups in common (group1 and group2).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still a bit unsure about this. My complete dataset has 247 hhid's and 15 groups. so should my matrix be t(DF[4:14]) ?

Comment: m1 is derived from the group columns only.  I have changed the index to exclude the first three columns so if you have a different number of group columns you don't need to change it as long as the group columns are all columns except the first 3.